# How to express the function $a(t)$ knowing a parametrization $a(\eta)$ and $t(\eta)$?

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, power-series, taylor-expansion, parametric

I have this function :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
    a(\eta) = \sqrt{\sin{2 \eta}},
\end{equation}
and this time variable :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
    t(\eta) = \int_0^\eta a(\eta') \, d\eta'.
\end{equation}
This integral is very difficult to express in an analytical way, because of the square-root.

I would like to know the function $a$ parametrized as a power series of $t$.  How can I achieve this ?

When $\eta$ is very small, I could get
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
    a(t) \approx (3 \, t)^{\frac{1}{3}}.
\end{equation}
When $\eta$ isn't so small, I'm expecting something like
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
    a(t) = (3 \, t)^{\frac{1}{3}} f(t),
\end{equation}
where $f(t)$ could be (?) Taylor expanded.  How to find this function ?